# Is there a reason to nest require function calls?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My company has some existing Javascript code that looks like this.

```
require([pathA], function (A) {
    require([pathB], function (B) {
        // use A and B
    });
});
```

I have been told not to write the follow:

```
require([pathA, pathB], function (A, B) {
    // use A and B
});
```

What issues does this first form take care of. I'd really like to understand because sometimes I may have 6 dependencies and it seems a bit strange that I have to create 6 nested require functions!

Comment: Does A depend on B or B depend on A or are they both completely independent scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Nesting require calls is a way to enforce order in the asynchronous setup. RequireJS loads modules asynchronously and the order in which they will be loaded / evaluated is indetermined. If for some reason it is necessary that `B` is always evaluated after `A`, then you would have to instruct requirejs to load `B` when you are sure that `A` is already loaded i.e. inside the coresponding callback. In most situations though you would use the second form and not care about the order of loading/evaluation.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. RequireJS is designed to take care of dependencies for you. Could you provide an example of A.js and B.js that would require the use of nested requires? I think that would really help.

Comment: I can't think of any that @Louis haven't listed already. May be he should copy and paste mine on top of his, so the whole is self-contained and acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

What artm said is correct. The order in your first code snippet forces module `A` to be loaded before module `B`. If I were presented with code like that and was told it cannot be rearranged like your second code snippet, my immediate answer would be "please provide a specific reason."

Here are some reasons I've encountered. I'm going to consider cases that diverge a bit from the code you show in your question, for the sake of completeness.

1. "I don't want to require jQuery everywhere. So I require it before loading my application."

   I consider this to be bad design. If a module is reused elsewhere, it won't necessarily be immediately evident that jQuery is required. Yes, you can read the code but I've got some modules where the only thing I use from jQuery is `$.data` and it is far down into the code. In all likelihood someone reading the code will miss it. And even if it is more evident, when people worry about dependencies they'll scan for `define` and `require` calls.
2. "I need to load a configuration file before my application starts."

   Often this is to avoid alternatives that are worse, extremely complicated or about as bad as nesting requires. Whether or not it is a bad design really depends on specifics of the case at hand.
3. The 2nd module is computed on the basis of the first. For instance:

   ```
   require(["modA"], function (A) {
        var modB = modA.something();
        require([modB], function (B) {
            // use A and B
        });
   });
   ```

   Note how `"modA"` is a literal, while `modB` is a variable. There are valid use case scenarios for this.
4. Easier error handling:

   ```
   require(["modA"], function (A) {
       require(["modB"], function (B) {
            ...
       }, function (err) {
            // I know if there's a problem here modB did not load properly..
       });
   });
   ```

   If you loaded the two modules with the same `require` you probably could analyze the error to figure out what happened. However, separating the modules makes it trivial to know that if the error handler is hit then `modB` did not load properly. Why might we check whether `modB` loaded properly or not rather than just let the whole application fail? Maybe `modB` is an optional module that adds functionality but is *not necessary* for the app to work. The error handler might set a status flag or provide some sort of null implementation of what `modB` would otherwise provide.

Answer (score 0):

artm's answer is correct.

The nested require calls imply *B* is dependent on *A*.  It might not be applicable, but consider specifying that in the modules:

```
// b.js
define([pathA], function (a) {});
```

Comment: Are you saying that if you author your modules correctly then the nested require is not necessary?

Comment: Yes, I think the nested require calls is a smell.